# Why can I fill my NSArray just with one object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

why can´t I fill my NSArray? Where is my mistake? He always just fill one object/image to the nsarray. I set a NSlog to check which value string has and he shows me all the 20 urls.

```
for (int i = 0, count = [bild count]; i < count; i = i++) {
    NSString * string = [bild objectAtIndex:i];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSData *datas = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:datas];
    myArray = [NSMutableArray array];      // this will autorelease, so if you need to keep it around, retain it
    [myArray addObject:img];
    int count = [myArray count];
    NSLog(@"There are %d elements in my array", count);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you refer to the compiler as he?

Comment: If it's not a simple typo, German nouns have gender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

everytime through your loop you are creating a new aray

```
 myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time through the loop, you're re-initializing your array. Move the array declaration out of the loop (before it) to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the NSMutable array outside the loop
2. Call addObject on the NSMutableArray